# Does initializing a class with braces guarantee that all member gets default initialized?

Tags: c++11, initialization, undefined, list-initialization

In the following example, does initializing a `Vec3` with braces guarantee that all of `x`, `y`, and `z` get default initialized (`func_a()`), in difference to `func_b()` where all members gets undefined values?

```
struct Vec2 { float x, y; };
struct Vec3 { Vec2 xy; float z; };
auto func_a() {
    Vec3 v{};
    return v;
}
auto func_b() {
    Vec3 v;
    return v;
}
```

If so, is there any exception where a member does not get initialized even if the class it belongs to get initialized with braces?

*Clang* and *GCC* yields different assembly for `func_b()`.

In *Clang* the assembly is a single `ret` statement.

In *GCC* the assembly is similar to func_a():

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-24], 0x00000000
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-20], 0x00000000
pxor    xmm1, xmm1
movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
ret
```

(Compiler explorer link https://godbolt.org/z/XqwgSV)

Comment: [This *value initialization* reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) should give you your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What corresponds to your example from the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> `T object {}; // (4) (since C++11)`
>
> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>   ...
>   4) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) is declared with the initializer consisting of a pair of braces.
>
> The effects of value initialization are:
>   ...
>   2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), **the object is zero-initialized** and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

So in your case, [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) will take place.

> If T is an non-union class type, **all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits**. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

Comment: That's not true. Both classes *have* a default constructor, so point 2 from your first link applies: "2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;". This means that all members will be set to 0 in OP's example.

Comment: @joe_chip:  Yes, you are correct. Updated the answer. I did not consider the "defaulted default" constructor.